# WHERE clause after UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "seekers" which contains a list of people. There is a column called "username" which contains the usernames of the people and a column called "resume_status" which either has a value of 0 or 1.

Currently the the query below does not check the "seekers" table at all. I would like it to only display results with the a value of "1" in the "resume_status" column.

NOTE: The only common column and value in the "seekers" table and the ones in the existing query below is the "username" column. My confusion comes from trying to figure out how to link the query below to the "seekers" table.

```
$query="
    (SELECT username, MATCH(highlight) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_highlights HAVING score>0 ORDER by score desc)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT username, MATCH(skill,skill_list) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_skills HAVING score >0 ORDER by score desc)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT username, MATCH(education_title,education_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_education HAVING score >0 ORDER by score desc)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT username, MATCH(employer_title,employer_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_employer HAVING score>0 ORDER by score desc)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT username, MATCH(volunteer_title,volunteer_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_volunteer HAVING score >0 ORDER by score desc)
";
```

Comment: Make the `union all ` a subquery and then you can join the results to another table or use a `where` clause.

Comment: Not sure what the proper syntax would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Brijesh's answer is good but I think this will be faster -- it will also improve with addition of one index on the seekers table and we want username indexes on the other tables.
..

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT a.username, MATCH(a.highlight) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
  FROM resume_highlights a
  JOIN seekers ON a.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
  HAVING score>0 

    UNION ALL

  SELECT b.username, MATCH(b.skill,b.skill_list) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
  FROM resume_skills b
  JOIN seekers ON b.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
  HAVING score >0 

    UNION ALL

  SELECT c.username, MATCH(c.education_title,c.education_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
  FROM resume_education c
  JOIN seekers ON c.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
  HAVING score >0 

    UNION ALL

  SELECT d.username, MATCH(d.employer_title,d.employer_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
  FROM resume_employer d
  JOIN seekers ON d.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
  HAVING score>0 

    UNION ALL

  SELECT e.username, MATCH(e.volunteer_title,e.volunteer_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
  FROM resume_volunteer e
  JOIN seekers ON e.username = seekers.username and seekers.resume_status = 1
  HAVING score >0 

) AS X
ORDER BY SCORE desc
```

Comment: When trying to run the above, I get this error... Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Did you leave in all the `()` you had before?

Comment: I don't have mysql handy but I made an edit -- did that help?

Comment: No... Strict copy/paste of your query with the exception that I added "desc" after the ORDER BY (I also edited your post to include it since I figured it was just a mistake)

Comment: Ya still getting the "Every derived table must have its own alias" error

Comment: Not an expert but does "seekers" need an alias?

Comment: @G-J  Try adding `AS X` before the `ORDER BY`

Comment: No error but I don't think the ORDER BY has any effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107357/discussion-between-g-j-and-hogan).

Comment: @G-J - saying something has no effect does not mean anything -- I can't see it.  Are you saying it is not ordered by SCORE -- maybe all the scores are the same value -- then the order by would have no effect.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Sorry... I just realized that the query outputs a result for each individual table and I have other code that groups it together in one resulting score. I guess a better query could be written so the extra code is not needed but this does the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use below query to sortout

```
SELECT A.username, A.score FROM
(
    (SELECT username, MATCH(highlight) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_highlights HAVING score>0 ORDER by score desc)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT username, MATCH(skill,skill_list) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_skills HAVING score >0 ORDER by score desc)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT username, MATCH(education_title,education_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_education HAVING score >0 ORDER by score desc)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT username, MATCH(employer_title,employer_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_employer HAVING score>0 ORDER by score desc)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT username, MATCH(volunteer_title,volunteer_organization) AGAINST (\"{$keywords}\" IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM resume_volunteer HAVING score >0 ORDER by score desc)
) A
LEFT JOIN 
seekers on A.username = seekers.username
WHERE seekers.resume_status = 1
```

Comment: You effectively made that LEFT into an INNER join by putting that field in the WHERE. You may want to change that.

Comment: @G-J - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IN operator to filter the usernames. 
OR
You can use Joins, by aliasing your query(called derived tables) and join with the "seekers" table on column "username", hence you can very well user other columns of your query.